# How to input a tab character using Windows Terminal + native SSH client?

Tags: bash, windows-terminal

I know that when using most SSH clients to remote to a bash terminal, I can use to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter a tab character.

But when using Windows Terminal, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> just pastes whatever content is in the clipboard.

How can I enter a tab character when using Windows Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, but I'm going to have to go from memory/theory on this a bit.

The WSL team changed the way that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> operates in Windows Terminal in April 2020, but [only for *new* installs](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5187#issuecomment-840169529).  So unless I uninstall/reinstall , I'm not going to be able to exactly reproduce what you are seeing.  And I don't plan on uninstalling/reinstalling because I *prefer* the old behavior.  I did attempt to bring up a VM where I have Windows Terminal installed (post-change), but I hadn't used it in a while and it's not quite functional at the moment.  So, from memory/theory it is ...

That said, the problem should be that the default keybindings in your installation have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> set to the Paste operation, as you've found.  Simply unbinding the key should allow the shell to handle its default behavior (the "verbatim insert" operation that will allow you to insert a Tab character).

If you are in a recent release of Windows Terminal:

- Go to *Settings*
- Select *Actions* on the left
- Scroll down to the *Paste* action which is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Click the Edit (pencil) icon
- Delete it with the Trash icon

I believe that *Paste* should still be bound to either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, or both.  If not, feel free to *Add* a new action and set it to one or the other, or whatever you want.

---

Side note:  As you can read in [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/968), the Windows Terminal team was torn between two groups here:

- Those of us who preferred the "Linux" terminal behavior to pass <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to the shell so that WSL distributions would handle it as *we* were used to.
- Windows users who expected <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to *Paste*, like it does in pretty much every other Windows application, but especially as it behaved in PowerShell and CMD under the old Windows Console.

I'm a long-time Windows user, but I'm personally happier having <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> be handled by the shell, even if that means I need a different key-chord for Paste under Windows Terminal.

But "the squeaky wheel gets the grease", so those who didn't like the Windows Terminal default behavior "asked" (perhaps "demanded", depending on how you read that Github issue) to have the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> behavior changed to be *Paste*, and so it was.

Either way, it was/is configurable.  It's just the default that has changed.  And that was probably the right call by Microsoft.  There are (logically) more users who expect the "Windows" behavior in Windows Terminal than those of us who expect (or want) the Linux behavior ;-).

Comment: oh crap, it didn't even crossed my mind to check shortcut settings! and yeah, I agree most users of a Windows environment would expect the same behaviour on this program as any other on it and it should be the default. Thanks!